# Unable to pull image from amazon ECS private repository on container instances running in ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have created a NON default cluster on AWS ECS and I am able to pull docker images from docker public repository and run it too for testing.

I then created a ECS private repo and built and pushed an image to this repository and it succeeds. But when I try to pull it manually using docker pull, it complains with following error:

> Error response from daemon: Get
>   https://532193077341.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v2/12r/manifests/latest: no basic auth credentials

It seems to be an issue with IAM roles and permissions but I am not sure which role/policy to change.

Comment: how can you push image into ECS private repo ? Is it ECR ?

Comment: @Apolozeus yeah I can push the images to ECS private repo.

Comment: can you check if you have `ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer, ecr:BatchGetImage and ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability` permission ?

Answer (score 1):

#### In your ECS container (task) definition

If you are using a private ECR repository:

Do **not** check *Private repository authentication* option, as ECR doesn't use username-password authentication, it will use the IAM role/user permissions. Then, just make sure that the ECS IAM role (called *ecsTaskExecutionRole* by default) have permissions to pull images from ECR, which if it doesn't add these lines yourself:

```
"ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
"ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
"ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
"ecr:BatchGetImage",
```

---

If you are using a non-ECR private repository:

**Check** *Private repository authentication* option and give your username-password using [Secrets Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate against ECR first.  Local AWS credentials on their own aren't enough to allow you to pull from a private ECR repository.  Try something like this beforehand:

```
$(aws ecr get-login --registry-ids <YOUR-ID> --region <YOUR-REGION>)
```

Which will perform a `docker login` for you against ECR, allowing you to pull private images (assuming your local AWS credentials have the required permission).

For more information, see "Step 1: Authenticate Docker to your Default Registry" within [the Amazon ECR Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ECR_AWSCLI.html).

Comment: I was expecting that on my ec2instance I shouldn't have to login and I should have been able to to pull images on my ec2Instance without logging in. As part of creation of my aws_launch_configuration, I specify the instance_profile which ties role with profile_policy. The profile policy has :

"ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
"ecr:BatchGetImage"
...

So I assume that on an instance I should be able to pull images manually without actually logging in to ecs registry manually.

Comment: And of course the above works just that I assumed the proper role, rolepolicy for instance which gets launched as part of launchconfiguration should not require logging in manually. I am not sure how does ecs-agent actually pull the image from repo when it runs a task definition on an instance.